# How to pull data from SQL Server 2016 to Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration, apex-webservice

Basically I need to fetch data from SQL Server 2016 and insert fetched data into salesforce. Can we do it by writing Salesforce REST API or Web Services API without using any third party tools or connectors?

If it is possible then can anybody share references or sample code for it?

Comment: This is definitely possible, but I don't have any example code for you. It may help others if you add more specifics about what you want to do. Is this a job you want to run regularly or a one time job, how much data are we talking about, is there a reason you don't want to use third party tools, what have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad and lacks specifics. Because we do not have information about the setup but here are a couple of things I can recommend  apart from writing your own code.

1. Using ODATA - You can download the Microsoft OData Source and use the your DB as an external object. No need for any connectors or other tools. You data will be available in External object (Not stored in SFDC).
2. Utilize an ETL and write jobs for it.
3. Go for paid tools.

**Writing your own code:**

I am sure you would have finalized the object structure and fields types already.

***Fetching data from SQL server***
Export using CSV or in any other format or fetch data using [JDBC/ODBC](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/retrieve-data-example/)

***Saving data in Salesforce***
Read the CSV file and use [partner/enterprise WSDL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_get_WSDLs.htm) or [Salesforce's rest api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm).

---

Migrating data from SQL server to Salesforce is not a small task and depends on:

1. Number of tables and fields
2. Data volume you have
3. Types of fields.
4. Current Salesforce structure etc,

   There is no one size fits all approach here. Maybe it will help to add more info about your current setup.